# Neat way to conditionally select elements from two lists?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = [-1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The number of elements in `a` and `b` are always the same.

I want to keep all the elements in `a` that are positive, and the corresponding elements of `b`.

One straightforward way would be

```
anew = []
bnew = []
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    if a[i] > 0:
         anew.append(a[i])
         bnew.append(b[i])
```

or something like

```
tmp = zip(*[(a[i], b[i]) for i in xrange(len(a)) if a[i]>0])
a = tmp[0] # The original a and b need not to be kept.
b = tmp[1]
```

I wonder if there is any shorter and cleaner (without any temporary variables) way for doing this.  Some kind of **in-place deletion** would be perfect, but if I use `del a[i], b[i]` in a loop, the index will be wrong after deletion of one element.

EDIT: What if the selection involves two lists, for example if the condition becomes

`if a[i] > 0 and b[i] > 0`?

Maybe in this case a temporary variable has to be used?

Comment: `but if I use del a[i], b[i] in a loop, the index will be wrong after deletion of one element.` What does this mean, are you also maintaining index of each number?

Comment: I mean, if I use a C-style loop, like: for i in xrange(len(a)): if a[i] < 0: del a[i], b[i], it will not work.

Comment: How about `anew = [[ai,b[a.index(ai)]] for ai in a if ai >= 0 ]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it could be shortest:

```
filter(lambda x:x[0]>0, zip(a,b))
```

Comment: You forgot to unzip ;-)

Comment: Thanks! A little bit edit of your answer gives the solution I was looking for: a, b = zip(*filter(lambda x:x[0]>0, zip(a,b)))

Comment: @FJDU: a, b = zip(*filter(lambda x:x[0]>0, zip(a,b))) makes a and b tuples.

Comment: That's fine.  Being iterable is enough.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `numpy`, there is a quite neat way:

```
In [117]: a = np.array([-1, 2, 3])
     ...: b = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [119]: a[a>0]
Out[119]: array([2, 3])

In [120]: b[a>0]
Out[120]: 
array(['b', 'c'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

If without `numpy`, you can use list comprehension with conditional statement:

```
In [121]: a = [-1, 2, 3]
     ...: b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [122]: print [i for i in a if i>0]
[2, 3]

In [124]: print [v for i, v in enumerate(b) if a[i]>0]
['b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "zip-filter-unzip" strategy:

Illustrating the steps:

```
>>> [(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b) if aa > 0]
[(2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
>>> zip(*[(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b) if aa > 0])
[(2, 3), ('b', 'c')]
```

The final result:

```
>>> aaa, bbb = zip(*[(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b) if aa > 0])
>>> aaa
(2, 3)
>>> bbb
('b', 'c')
```

As you can see, I have given you a pair of tuples -- Not a pair of lists.  In a lot of applications, that doesn't really matter, but if it does, the conversion isn't too difficult ;-)

This also extends to cover the case where both lists need to have an element greater than 0:

```
aaa, bbb = zip(*[(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a,b) if aa > 0 and bb > 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two steps. It's not 'shorter' but definitely simple and clean.

```
b = [b[i] for i in xrange(len(b)) if a[i] > 0]
a = [x for x in a if x > 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some functional tools can do this in one line, and quite nicely.:

```
anew, bnew = map(lambda x: list(x), zip(*filter(lambda z: z[0] > 0, zip(a, b))))
```

Comment: I don't think the lambda is necessary, is it?  can't you just use `list`?

Answer (score 0):

If order of elements does not matter to you, then you can swap the last element with the current element which is negative. Following is the code for my idea.

```
l = len(a)
i = 0
while i < l:
    print i,l
    while a[i] < 0:
        a[i] = a[-1]
        b[i] = b[-1]
        a.pop()
        b.pop()
        global l
        l = len(a)
    i = i+1


print a
print b
```